# Structuring Class Objects And Defining The Variables

Tags: java

I am trying to create an outline of what a character is in a game.

Then I want to create 10 different characters and compare their stats at different levels.

I am creating a class called `Character` that looks like this,

```
public class Character {

    String primaryAtribute; 

    double strength;
    double agility;
    double inteligence;
    double armor;
    double damageMultiplyer;
    int health;
    int mana;
    int range;
    int movement;
    int level;
    int damageMin;
    int damageMax;

    public Character() {

    } //constructor ends            

    private static int randomInt(int min, int max) { 
        return min + (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)); 
    }

    int damageRange = randomInt(damageMin, damageMax);
    double damage = damageRange + level * damageMultiplyer;

} //class ends
```

Then I am creating each character like this,

```
public class FirstCharacter {

    String primaryAtribute = "Agility"; 

    int level = 0;

    double strength = 17 + level * 1.9;
    double agility = 26 + level * 1.9;
    double inteligence = 15 + level * 1.4;
    double armor = 0.64;
    double damageMultiplyer = 1.9;

    int health = 473;
    int mana = 195;
    int range = 625;
    int movement = 300;
    int damageMin = 44;
    int damageMax = 55;
}
```

Am I on the right path here?

Once I create each character's class how would I go about setting which ever one I may pick to the `Character` class?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: OO design is a huge topic -- there are entire sections of libraries on it.  But what you have here probably won't work as you'd want it to in Java.

Comment: @VinceEmigh: Not really -- the code is quite broken as it stands.

Comment: lol , thanks Ill keep reading!

Comment: @cHao How is it broken when there is no code even being executed? The OP is asking if his code has good structure, and if he should continue using it or maybe switch to something more efficient

Comment: I tried writing an answer but I realized that there are a lot of things you need to understand before. So, I would really suggest you to read a tutorial/book of Java.

Comment: @Vince: Take a look at the `strength`, `agility`, etc fields in `FirstCharacter`.  Their values will always be as if the character were level 0.  (Or, you could set them each time the level changes.  But they'll always be initialized to the level-0 values.)

Comment: What you probably want to do is instantiate the `Character` class, which is not what you're doing here. Your actual code shows two completely different classes, having attributes with the same names.

Comment: @cHao I am going to fill in the level as I compare the characters. Why does the characters level have anything to do with my question? I want to know if I structure this like this can i run the characters through the character class and compare their attributes.

Comment: @cHao The *question* isn't about the functionality of the code, though - it's about a simple review of what he has and whether he's on the right track.

Comment: @NichoDiaz: No, you can't, because setting `level` in the future won't change `strength`'s value.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: The functionality has to be there, though; Code Review doesn't accept non-working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have recommended, you should probably just read a book on OOP. However, briefly:

The code you gave creates two, entirely unrelated types of objects, `Character` and `FirstCharacter`. However, it appears that what you really want to do is create an instance of the character class, like so:

```
Character firstChar = new Character();
```

and then use accessor methods or other means to set the character's attributes. For instance, if the fields were public (not recommended) you could do:

```
firstChar.strength = 17;
firstChar.agility = 26;
...
```

You will need to recalculate these values later when the level changes, you cannot specify a formula for them in the way you attempted to.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

As the comments before me have recommended, there are some OO principles you should understand beforehand. I'll try to outline some of them that could put you on the right track though.

Interfaces:

```
interface Character {
    // define methods that must be defined across all character types
    public void getLevel();
    public void getAgility();
    ...
}
```

Implementing this interface:

```
public class Bob implements Character {
    private String primaryAtribute; 
    private double strength;
    private double agility;
    private double inteligence;
    private double armor;
    private double damageMultiplyer;
    private int health;
    private int mana;
    private int range;
    private int movement;
    private int level;
    private int damageMin;
    private int damageMax;

    // default constructor
    public Bob() {}

    // override as many times as you'd like
    public Bob(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    // getters and setters - required to implement ALL from interface
    public void getLevel() {
        return this.level;
    }

    public void getAgility() {
        return this.agility;
    }

    public void setAgility(double agility) {
        this.agility = agility;
    }
}
```

From hereon we can use Bob where-ever we like, as a new instance: `new Bob(...);`.

Most member variables are always private, for encapsulation. This all depends on your use-case and how you'd like to structure the program though. For instance you could have change `health` to `public int health`, and you'd be able to access this without a `getHealth()` function, you'd be able to directly call `[instance of Bob].health`.

The topics I covered, briefly, were class variables, interfaces, scope, overloading, probably something else. You'd need to pick up a book, or even read through the Java docs. They have some good examples and are quite verbose.

Comment: If you're going to add a getter that fetches the field and returns it unchanged, and a setter that blindly sets it, you might as well just make the field `public` -- you've already tossed out everything the setter was good for.

Comment: @cHao Setters still has the advantage of allowing edits in function without requiring a change in codebase in the future. i.e. when you want to make `setAgility` check for nonnull before actually writing it to the field, and you let the field public, changing it requires a codebase change, which will not be favourable for users in most cases.

Comment: This is an example. Also why I noted that your use-case would determine how you'd access your variables. And even the Oracle docs (for learning), say to use simple set methods as above.

Comment: @Sam: Oracle's docs are focused more on the language itself than on decent OO techniques.  The truth is, outside of "struct"-like data holders and beans, most setters you see shouldn't be there.  They typically exist because of cargo-cult programming, and their very existence typically indicates a wrongheadedness about what "encapsulation" actually means.

Comment: @Unihedron: Good luck setting a `double` to `null`.  But either way, if you change the rules about what's a valid value, you'll also probably want to throw an exception when someone attempts to set an invalid value -- which will require code changes anyway, since code that used to work just fine will now crash the app.

Comment: @cHao So as we sum up this short discussion, the use of setters really depends on the design. My personal preference is to use setters, your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Unihedron: Depends on the design to a degree...but a design that calls for setters for everything breaks encapsulation almost by definition.  Don't provide setters for stuff that shouldn't be arbitrarily settable, and most stuff shouldn't be arbitrarily settable.

Comment: I keep getting errors on all  my get  public void getLevel() {
        return this.level;
    } Does that look right? It appears in the interface I say public void if I change void to the type then declare the same type in the class it clears the errors.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The interface, much like header files for C, defines the inputs and outputs of a function and they must be implemented verbatim. Anything that returns, must have their return type defined. So you'd have `public int getLevel() { return this.level; }` instead of `public void getLevel() { return this.level; }`.

Comment: So to sum this up, 1 create interface to define what methods will be used. 2. create a general character class that adds my setters getters  and define variable types. 3. create a new class for each specific character and use `Character myfirstcharacter new Character("Agility", 0 /* , ... */); ` ???

Answer (score 2):

So sorry for being late, traffic was a nightmare. Here are possibilities of what you could do:

#### A. Establish a proper constructor

```
public class Character {

    // ...

    public Character(String primaryAttribute, int level /* , ... */){
        this.primaryAttribute = primaryAttribute;
        this.level = level;
        // Write all fields with constructor variables.
    }
}
```

From there you can use:

```
{
    Character myfirstcharacter = new Character("Agility", 0 /* , ... */);
}
```

#### B. Extend new class

```
public class FirstCharacter extends Character {
    {
        primaryAtribute = "Agility";

        level = 0;

        strength = 17 + level * 1.9;
        agility = 26 + level * 1.9;
        inteligence = 15 + level * 1.4;
        armor = 0.64;
        damageMultiplyer = 1.9;

        health = 473;
        mana = 195;
        range = 625;
        movement = 300;
        damageMin = 44;
        damageMax = 55;
    }
}
```

This is a class that extends your `Character` class and writes to its fields when constructed.

```
{
    Character myfirstcharacter = new FirstCharacter();
    // FirstCharacter myfirstcharacter = new FirstCharacter();
}
```

#### C. Initialize with anonymous class

This is like option **B**:

```
{
    Character myfirstcharacter = new Character() {
        {
            primaryAtribute = "Agility";

            level = 0;

            strength = 17 + level * 1.9;
            agility = 26 + level * 1.9;
            inteligence = 15 + level * 1.4;
            armor = 0.64;
            damageMultiplyer = 1.9;

            health = 473;
            mana = 195;
            range = 625;
            movement = 300;
            damageMin = 44;
            damageMax = 55;
        }
    }
}
```

#### D. Use an Interface instead

[Please see Sam's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977328/structuring-class-objects-and-defining-the-variables/24977517#24977517)

Comment: @Sam You were too quick on interfaces, hehe. So I linked to your answer instead of writing what I originally intended to write.

Comment: You are a great person! Thank you so much! This is great.

Comment: @NichoDiaz You're welcome. [If you'd like to read more, there was a short, relevant discussion related to constructing objects like these in the chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17806814#17806814)

Comment: Awesome I will check it out. 
I really appreciate you guys spelling all that out for me. It all makes sense but what is the more professional way to go about it? Sam's interface or one of your other examples?

Comment: @NichoDiaz It depends on your class design. If you use these classes a lot, it's better to use a constructor. If the type matters, you would extend a new class. If you're lazy, you would use an anonymous class, and if you're writing good code, use an interface.

Comment: @NichoDiaz Using both would be a good idea. An example would be an interface for plants. A base class would implement this interface. A tree would extend this plant class. A shrub would also extend the plant class.

Comment: Note, B and C both require that all the fields you set, not be private.  (And if the subclass is in a different package, the default visibility won't work either.  You'd need either `protected` or `public`.)